# Kafka Sink Connector with one-to-many connection

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

My question is about Kafka Sink Connector configuration.

I have a specific case:
There is one topic, which contains messages with entity info:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "name",
  "attributes": {
     "attr1":{ value: val1, type: typ1},
     "attr2":{ value: val2, type: typ2}        
  }
}
```

I need Kafka Sink Connector to save it in two tables in the following way:

```
|id|name|
|1|name|


|parent_id|name|value|type|
|1|attr1|val1|typ1|
|1|attr2|val2|typ2|
```

So I need to save it in two tables and keep one-to-many connection

Could Kafka Sink Connector be figured in such way at all?

Answer (score 1):

JDBC Sink connect can only write one topic to one table.

You could fork the code to do whatever you want with the data, however, if you so choose

Comment: can you elaborate on forking the code please? you mean two connectors?

Comment: No. JDBC connector is open source on Github. Download the code. Change it to do whatever you want